# How to execute the master go scritpt in kubernetes

Tags: go, kubernetes

We have found the list of tests in the below URL. Can anyone please let me know the main go script to execute the list of test for end-to-end kubernetes test.
    https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/tree/master/test/e2e

We have already installed kubernetes in Ubuntu and trying to get the main script that executes all the e2e test.

I have problem in installing kubetest. Please help me to solve the issue. The complete information is given below.

```
chan@coe-OptiPlex-3060:~$ sudo go get -v -u k8s.io/test-infra/kubetest
Fetching https://k8s.io/test-infra/kubetest?go-get=1
Parsing meta tags from https://k8s.io/test-infra/kubetest?go-get=1 (status code 200)
get "k8s.io/test-infra/kubetest": found meta tag get.metaImport{Prefix:"k8s.io/test-infra", VCS:"git", RepoRoot:"https://github.com/kubernetes/test-infra"} at https://k8s.io/test-infra/kubetest?go-get=1
get "k8s.io/test-infra/kubetest": verifying non-authoritative meta tag
Fetching https://k8s.io/test-infra?go-get=1
Parsing meta tags from https://k8s.io/test-infra?go-get=1 (status code 200)
k8s.io/test-infra (download)
github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-go (download)
github.com/Azure/go-autorest (download)
github.com/dgrijalva/jwt-go (download)
github.com/Azure/azure-storage-blob-go (download)
github.com/Azure/azure-pipeline-go (download)
github.com/mattn/go-ieproxy (download)
github.com/aws/aws-k8s-tester (download)
package github.com/aws/aws-k8s-tester/ekstester: cannot find package "github.com/aws/aws-k8s-tester/ekstester" in any of:
    /usr/lib/go-1.10/src/github.com/aws/aws-k8s-tester/ekstester (from $GOROOT)
    /home/coe/go/src/github.com/aws/aws-k8s-tester/ekstester (from $GOPATH)
github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go (download)
github.com/docker/docker (download)
github.com/pelletier/go-toml (download)
github.com/satori/go.uuid (download)
github.com/spf13/pflag (download)
Fetching https://golang.org/x/crypto/ssh?go-get=1
Parsing meta tags from https://golang.org/x/crypto/ssh?go-get=1 (status code 200)
get "golang.org/x/crypto/ssh": found meta tag get.metaImport{Prefix:"golang.org/x/crypto", VCS:"git", RepoRoot:"https://go.googlesource.com/crypto"} at https://golang.org/x/crypto/ssh?go-get=1
get "golang.org/x/crypto/ssh": verifying non-authoritative meta tag
Fetching https://golang.org/x/crypto?go-get=1
Parsing meta tags from https://golang.org/x/crypto?go-get=1 (status code 200)
golang.org/x/crypto (download)
Fetching https://golang.org/x/crypto/chacha20?go-get=1
Parsing meta tags from https://golang.org/x/crypto/chacha20?go-get=1 (status code 200)
get "golang.org/x/crypto/chacha20": found meta tag get.metaImport{Prefix:"golang.org/x/crypto", VCS:"git", RepoRoot:"https://go.googlesource.com/crypto"} at https://golang.org/x/crypto/chacha20?go-get=1
get "golang.org/x/crypto/chacha20": verifying non-authoritative meta tag
Fetching https://golang.org/x/crypto/internal/subtle?go-get=1
Parsing meta tags from https://golang.org/x/crypto/internal/subtle?go-get=1 (status code 200)
get "golang.org/x/crypto/internal/subtle": found meta tag get.metaImport{Prefix:"golang.org/x/crypto", VCS:"git", RepoRoot:"https://go.googlesource.com/crypto"} at https://golang.org/x/crypto/internal/subtle?go-get=1
get "golang.org/x/crypto/internal/subtle": verifying non-authoritative meta tag
Fetching https://golang.org/x/crypto/curve25519?go-get=1
Parsing meta tags from https://golang.org/x/crypto/curve25519?go-get=1 (status code 200)
get "golang.org/x/crypto/curve25519": found meta tag get.metaImport{Prefix:"golang.org/x/crypto", VCS:"git", RepoRoot:"https://go.googlesource.com/crypto"} at https://golang.org/x/crypto/curve25519?go-get=1
get "golang.org/x/crypto/curve25519": verifying non-authoritative meta tag
Fetching https://golang.org/x/crypto/ed25519?go-get=1
Parsing meta tags from https://golang.org/x/crypto/ed25519?go-get=1 (status code 200)
get "golang.org/x/crypto/ed25519": found meta tag get.metaImport{Prefix:"golang.org/x/crypto", VCS:"git", RepoRoot:"https://go.googlesource.com/crypto"} at https://golang.org/x/crypto/ed25519?go-get=1
get "golang.org/x/crypto/ed25519": verifying non-authoritative meta tag
Fetching https://golang.org/x/crypto/ed25519/internal/edwards25519?go-get=1
Parsing meta tags from https://golang.org/x/crypto/ed25519/internal/edwards25519?go-get=1 (status code 200)
get "golang.org/x/crypto/ed25519/internal/edwards25519": found meta tag get.metaImport{Prefix:"golang.org/x/crypto", VCS:"git", RepoRoot:"https://go.googlesource.com/crypto"} at https://golang.org/x/crypto/ed25519/internal/edwards25519?go-get=1
get "golang.org/x/crypto/ed25519/internal/edwards25519": verifying non-authoritative meta tag
Fetching https://golang.org/x/crypto/poly1305?go-get=1
Parsing meta tags from https://golang.org/x/crypto/poly1305?go-get=1 (status code 200)
get "golang.org/x/crypto/poly1305": found meta tag get.metaImport{Prefix:"golang.org/x/crypto", VCS:"git", RepoRoot:"https://go.googlesource.com/crypto"} at https://golang.org/x/crypto/poly1305?go-get=1
get "golang.org/x/crypto/poly1305": verifying non-authoritative meta tag
Fetching https://k8s.io/client-go/kubernetes?go-get=1
Parsing meta tags from https://k8s.io/client-go/kubernetes?go-get=1 (status code 200)
get "k8s.io/client-go/kubernetes": found meta tag get.metaImport{Prefix:"k8s.io/client-go", VCS:"git", RepoRoot:"https://github.com/kubernetes/client-go"} at https://k8s.io/client-go/kubernetes?go-get=1
get "k8s.io/client-go/kubernetes": verifying non-authoritative meta tag
Fetching https://k8s.io/client-go?go-get=1
Parsing meta tags from https://k8s.io/client-go?go-get=1 (status code 200)
k8s.io/client-go (download)
Fetching https://k8s.io/client-go/discovery?go-get=1
Parsing meta tags from https://k8s.io/client-go/discovery?go-get=1 (status code 200)
get "k8s.io/client-go/discovery": found meta tag get.metaImport{Prefix:"k8s.io/client-go", VCS:"git", RepoRoot:"https://github.com/kubernetes/client-go"} at https://k8s.io/client-go/discovery?go-get=1
get "k8s.io/client-go/discovery": verifying non-authoritative meta tag
github.com/golang/protobuf (download)
github.com/googleapis/gnostic (download)
Fetching https://gopkg.in/yaml.v2?go-get=1
Parsing meta tags from https://gopkg.in/yaml.v2?go-get=1 (status code 200)
get "gopkg.in/yaml.v2": found meta tag get.metaImport{Prefix:"gopkg.in/yaml.v2", VCS:"git", RepoRoot:"https://gopkg.in/yaml.v2"} at https://gopkg.in/yaml.v2?go-get=1
gopkg.in/yaml.v2 (download)
Fetching https://k8s.io/apimachinery/pkg/api/errors?go-get=1
Parsing meta tags from https://k8s.io/apimachinery/pkg/api/errors?go-get=1 (status code 200)
get "k8s.io/apimachinery/pkg/api/errors": found meta tag get.metaImport{Prefix:"k8s.io/apimachinery", VCS:"git", RepoRoot:"https://github.com/kubernetes/apimachinery"} at https://k8s.io/apimachinery/pkg/api/errors?go-get=1
get "k8s.io/apimachinery/pkg/api/errors": verifying non-authoritative meta tag
Fetching https://k8s.io/apimachinery?go-get=1
Parsing meta tags from https://k8s.io/apimachinery?go-get=1 (status code 200)
k8s.io/apimachinery (download)
Fetching https://k8s.io/apimachinery/pkg/apis/meta/v1?go-get=1
Parsing meta tags from https://k8s.io/apimachinery/pkg/apis/meta/v1?go-get=1 (status code 200)
get "k8s.io/apimachinery/pkg/apis/meta/v1": found meta tag get.metaImport{Prefix:"k8s.io/apimachinery", VCS:"git", RepoRoot:"https://github.com/kubernetes/apimachinery"} at https://k8s.io/apimachinery/pkg/apis/meta/v1?go-get=1
```

..
..
    Parsing meta tags from https://k8s.io/client-go/pkg/apis/clientauthentication/v1alpha1?go-get=1 (status code 200)
 ..
..

```
Fetching https://k8s.io/test-infra/kubetest/process?go-get=1
Parsing meta tags from https://k8s.io/test-infra/kubetest/process?go-get=1 (status code 200)
get "k8s.io/test-infra/kubetest/process": found meta tag get.metaImport{Prefix:"k8s.io/test-infra", VCS:"git", RepoRoot:"https://github.com/kubernetes/test-infra"} at https://k8s.io/test-infra/kubetest/process?go-get=1
get "k8s.io/test-infra/kubetest/process": verifying non-authoritative meta tag
Fetching https://k8s.io/test-infra/kubetest/util?go-get=1
Parsing meta tags from https://k8s.io/test-infra/kubetest/util?go-get=1 (status code 200)
get "k8s.io/test-infra/kubetest/util": found meta tag get.metaImport{Prefix:"k8s.io/test-infra", VCS:"git", RepoRoot:"https://github.com/kubernetes/test-infra"} at https://k8s.io/test-infra/kubetest/util?go-get=1
get "k8s.io/test-infra/kubetest/util": verifying non-authoritative meta tag
Fetching https://k8s.io/test-infra/kubetest/kind?go-get=1
Parsing meta tags from https://k8s.io/test-infra/kubetest/kind?go-get=1 (status code 200)
get "k8s.io/test-infra/kubetest/kind": found meta tag get.metaImport{Prefix:"k8s.io/test-infra", VCS:"git", RepoRoot:"https://github.com/kubernetes/test-infra"} at https://k8s.io/test-infra/kubetest/kind?go-get=1
get "k8s.io/test-infra/kubetest/kind": verifying non-authoritative meta tag
Fetching https://k8s.io/test-infra/kubetest/kubeadmdind?go-get=1
Parsing meta tags from https://k8s.io/test-infra/kubetest/kubeadmdind?go-get=1 (status code 200)
get "k8s.io/test-infra/kubetest/kubeadmdind": found meta tag get.metaImport{Prefix:"k8s.io/test-infra", VCS:"git", RepoRoot:"https://github.com/kubernetes/test-infra"} at https://k8s.io/test-infra/kubetest/kubeadmdind?go-get=1
get "k8s.io/test-infra/kubetest/kubeadmdind": verifying non-authoritative meta tag
```

chan@coe-OptiPlex-3060:~$ kubetest --extract=v1.13.0
kubetest: command not found

Comment: The `README.md` file in that directory seems to link to some pretty extensive documentation.  What trouble are you having?

Comment: Hi David Maze, I was looking for main script name. So that i can run the go script using go run command.  I am also searching for any other ways to execute the end to end conformance test.

Answer (score 0):

Follow the below mentioned steps:

### Install Go

```
wget https://dl.google.com/go/go1.12.1.linux-amd64.tar.gz

sudo tar -C /usr/local -xzf go1.12.1.linux-amd64.tar.gz
export GOPATH="/home/vagrant/go"
export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/go/bin:$GOPATH/bin
```

### Install kubetest

```
go get -v -u k8s.io/test-infra/kubetest
```

### Extract the Version

```
kubetest --extract=v1.13.0

cd kubernetes
```

### Testing against local clusters

```
export KUBECONFIG=/path/to/kubeconfig
export KUBE_MASTER_IP="http://127.0.0.1:<PORT>"
export KUBE_MASTER_IP="127.0.0.1:<PORT>"
export KUBE_MASTER=local



kubetest --test --provider=skeleton --test_args="--ginkgo.focus=\[Conformance\]" | tee test.out
```

Comment: Thanks Prakash for your detailed information. I tried to install kubetest but it is throwing status code as 200. I have mentioned the log in the description section of this post.

Comment: These are indeed the documented instructions. However, the documented instructions do not work, even for 1.13. Good luck with anything newer.

Comment: This is a current question in a course on Udemy; the e2e used to install this way, but it does not currently.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me, not sure if all the steps are necessary:

```
# get kubetest, ginkgo and gomega

go get -u k8s.io/test-infra/kubetest
go get github.com/onsi/ginkgo/ginkgo
go get github.com/onsi/gomega/...

# Install Google SDK: https://cloud.google.com/sdk/docs/downloads-versioned-archives
# Login into Google Developer Cloud, necessary to fetch kubetest binaries with extract command

gcloud auth login

# Get the binaries
# WARNING: it removes all directories with kubernetes in the name (weird), it removed my kubernetes-the-hard-way repo, thus better switch to an empty dir before proceeding
kubetest --extract=v1.18.2
cd kubernetes

# Get the kubernetes client config
# I am using my own setup to deploy k8s using ansible/kubeadm here: https://github.com/earthquakesan/kubernetes-the-hard-way
# simply go into vagrant/, then do vagrant up
# after VMs are up, follow the 18-kubeadm.md guide

scp master-1:/home/vagrant/.kube/config ./

# Finally run the tests

export KUBECONFIG=$(pwd)/config
export KUBE_MASTER_IP=192.168.5.30:6443
export KUBE_MASTER_URL=https://192.168.5.30:6443
export KUBE_MASTER=master-1
export KUBERNETES_PROVIDER=skeleton
kubetest --test --test_args="--ginkgo.focus=\[Conformance\]" > test.out
```